# Why same JAVA program is working differently in different Platforms like Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, linux, windows, amazon-ec2

Same peace of JAVA program is working differently in different platform .

For example I wrote a JAVA for combining different Tiff files stored in a folder to Multi Page Tiff.

Please find below the program.

```
 public String merge(String dirPath) {
        String inputDir = dirPath;
        File faxSource = new File(inputDir);
        File file[] = faxSource.listFiles();

        int numImages = file.length;
        String name = "";
        List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        Arrays.sort(file, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
                name = name + file[i].getName();
                SeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream(file[i]);
                ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff",
                        ss, null);

                int numPages = decoder.getNumPages();
                for (int j = 0; j < numPages; j++) {
                    PlanarImage op = new NullOpImage(
                            decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(j), null, null,
                            OpImage.OP_IO_BOUND);
                    images.add(op.getAsBufferedImage());
                }
            }

            // name=UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".tiff";

            TIFFEncodeParam params = new TIFFEncodeParam();
            params.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_DEFLATE);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inputDir + "\\" + name);
            ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("tiff", out,
                    params);
            // encoder.
            List<BufferedImage> imageList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
            for (int i = 1; i < images.size(); i++) {
                imageList.add(images.get(i));
            }
            params.setExtraImages(imageList.iterator());
            encoder.encode(images.get(0));
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return inputDir + "\\" + name;
    }
```

Assume that the folder contains 4 tiff images (A.tiff,B.tiff,C,.tiff,D.tiff).These Tiff files are downloaded from the S# in order.

If I am running the above program in a windows Server It is doing Collation in the order A.tiff+B.tiff+**C.tiff+D.tiff**.

If I am running the same program in Amazon EC2 Linux am getting the output A.tiff+B.tiff+**D.tiff+C.tiff**.

Any Idea why the same JAVA code is running differently in Windows and Linux?

Comment: Seems that `lastModified` timestamps are wrong or not precise enough?

Comment: But files are downloaded inorder from s3. So the time stamp's are different for different files.

Comment: You need to look at the modified timestamp in both cases. Depending how you are downloading them, the modified timestamp may be the time when it was created on the system.

Comment: Not sure what happened to your timestamps. Can you write an explicit ordering as part of your download process? Maybe put a sequence number in the file name, or write an addition text file with the correct order. That should be more stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file system on your Linux box; the precision of modification date for `EXT3`, which I'm guessing it's using, is 1 second. If you download two files within one second, they may both have the same times.

Windows, on the other hand, normally uses NTFS, which has 100 nanosecond precision on file times.

Comment: "within one second". And that could happen when you download from S3 to EC2.